# Is there autogenerated code for Flurl using swagger.json?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.2, flurl

There are some client generators (eg. Postman, Swagger-codegen https://editor.swagger.io/) that uses libraries such as Restsharp to automatically generate classes for a given swagger.json from an API.

Is there any client generator that does that using Flurl?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'd gladly support the effort if anyone wants to tackle it :)

Comment: Plus 1 to someone making this a reality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To date 19th May 2019 there is none (to the best of my and Google's knowledge).